# python: custom sort: not purely lexicographical but reverse and shortest common first

Tags: python, sorting, lexicographic, lexicographic-ordering, custom-sort

### Background

I want to sort reverse but not strict lexicographical and then it gets even more weird.. :P

The reason is that a proprietary software parses directories exactly the way I describe here and I want to copy that behavior.

### Requirements (in that order)

1. both: python2 and python3 compatible
2. Reverse lexicographical
3. shortest common first

### Example data

The following is an example of (random ordered) input data for that python script:

```
IA-test-PROD-me
ia-test-prod-me
ia-test-me-staging
ia-test-me
ia-test-STAGING-me
IA-test-me
IA-test-me-staging
ia-test-me-prod
IA-test-me-STAGING
IA-test-me-prod
IA-test-me-PROD
IA-test-STAGING-me
```

### How it should look like

I store that in a list and need to sort it that it looks at the end like:

```
ia-test-me
ia-test-prod-me
ia-test-me-staging
ia-test-me-prod
ia-test-STAGING-me
IA-test-me
IA-test-me-staging
IA-test-me-prod
IA-test-me-STAGING
IA-test-me-PROD
IA-test-STAGING-me
IA-test-PROD-me
```

### Code

From what I understood `sort()` and `sorted()` are stable funcs which sort lexicographically. But as I need to run all the above requirements I am stuck atm..

```py
def sortLexo(input_list):
    words = input_list.split()
    words.sort(reverse=True)
 
    for i in words:
        print(i)
```

The problem is `sort()` + `reverse=True` alone is not enough as it does not fulfill the requirement 3 (shortest first) above:

```
           <-------------. should be placed here
ia-test-prod-me          |
ia-test-me-staging      /|\
ia-test-me-prod          |
ia-test-me    -------> wrong
ia-test-STAGING-me
           <--------------- should be placed here
IA-test-me-staging        |
IA-test-me-prod          /|\
IA-test-me-STAGING        |
IA-test-me-PROD           |
IA-test-me    --------> wrong
IA-test-STAGING-me
IA-test-PROD-me
```

I've played around with `groupby` to sort by length but I get nowhere (my python kl isn't that deep) .. :(

I guess it is super easy to do for someone with good python know how.. any help appreciated !

Comment: I don't think what your asking would be considered a "stable" sort, since I think the output might depend on the order of the input.

Comment: the input should not matter as it can be random. 
the sort which I need then must be stable though.

Comment: Are you sure that `ia-test-me` should be above `ia-test-prod-me`.  I would think it should be under it.

Comment: yes.. the proprietary software parses exactly that way.. its how they apply settings or better said inherit configuration settings..

Comment: Your input list has 9 items, your output example has 12 items… this is not a stable sort nor a sort altogether.

Comment: sorry copy/paste issue for the inputs list. corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to piece this together based on the description.  It seems like you want to pad the right side of the comparison string with the highest character you expect to receive (I use the character 0xFF, but if you're using Unicode instead of ASCII you might need a higher number).

```
MAX_LENGTH = max(len(word) for word in words)
sorted(words, key=lambda word: word + "\xFF" * (MAX_LENGTH - len(word)), reverse=True)
```

This will produce the following.  Although it's different from your question, I can't understand what specification would produce the output in the question.

```
ia-test-prod-me
ia-test-me
ia-test-me-staging
ia-test-me-prod
ia-test-STAGING-me
IA-test-me
IA-test-me-staging
IA-test-me-prod
IA-test-me-STAGING
IA-test-me-PROD
IA-test-STAGING-me
IA-test-PROD-me
```

What the code does is this: the key function created the key for comparison.  In this case, we take the word and pad the right side of it with the highest character that we would expect to find in the string; that is the code `"\xFF" * (MAX_LENGTH - len(word))`.  It might seem strange to use the multiplication operator on a string but it works and creates a string the length that you multiply it by; in this case the difference between the maximum string length and the length of the current string.  In normal alphabetical sorting (like in the dictionary), words that are shorter come first in the sort order.  Padding with the highest character makes strings that match until the end of the shorter string (like say `ia-test-me` and `ia-test-me-staging`) put the shorter string last (in this case first since we reverse the whole list with `reverse=True`).

Comment: wow thx for that quick answer! 

> " I can't understand what specification would produce the output in the question"

a proprietary software parses directories that way to apply settings or better overwrites that way (ia-test-me-prod overwrites ia-test-me-staging and ia-test-me)


sorry for my ignorance but could you adapt the above to my code snippet above? I am not sure how v and l refer to my code :P sorry I am a python n00b :(

Comment: omg got it.. its just:

`MAX_LENGTH = max(len(v) for v in words)`
`sorted(words, key=lambda v: v + "\xFF" * (MAX_LENGTH - len(v)), reverse=True)` . That works perfectly fine! thx again, you saved my day!

Comment: would it be possible to explain what your code does exactly? I want to understand how it works.. @tim-ludwinski

Comment: I added an explanation at the bottom of the post and also updated the variables `l` to be `words` (like in your example) and `v` to be `word`.

Comment: Also, your example data and "How it should look like" are different lengths.

Comment: thx for the explanation! sorry copy/paste issue for the inputs list. corrected.

Comment: found one issue which I just found out now: in that order `And-test-me` would be shown 
 after `IA-test-PROD-me` but it needs to be before IA. it seems that the order that I need is prioritizing all capital letters first. so other then in a lexicographical order where it compares character by character it prioritizes `IA` over `An`.. damn.. any idea how that could be solved? thx again for all your help here!!

Comment: any chance for the above Tim? I know its weird but I am so stuck.. :(((

Comment: If you don't define exactly how the sorting is supposed to work, you might never be able to get something to sort that way.  As for the change in sorting, in the sort key function you can call a function that will reverse capitalization of the letters.  Writing such a function shouldn't be too hard (just capitalize all lower case letters and lower case all capital letters).